# Merging two accounts: what happens if on one of them I'm banned from asking

Tags: discussion, user-accounts, post-ban, merge-accounts

I have another account, maybe more, I don't remember, the last time I logged to one of them maybe 2 years ago or more.

On one of them I'm banned from asking on askubuntu I think,because I didn't know back then that it's only for ubuntu, and on this one I'm banned from asking on serverfault I think,

What would happen if I merge the accounts together, would I be banned from using askubuntu and serverfault? one of them? both of them? None of them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The post ban check is being done "on the fly" meaning when you try asking new question or posting a new answer.

So, if the merged account fails the check you will still be banned, otherwise no ban for you.

Comment: Can I predict the result? just to if i should go ahead and ask the support team to merge or not

Comment: Try raw sum of score from both accounts. The more negative the result is, the risk of ban is higher.

Comment: seems like hard work, thanks :)

Comment: @Fischer Not really; all it takes it a quick scan through of questions and answers of both accounts. Sort by votes and visit the last page of results, count how many have negative votes.

Comment: @ʎǝʞuoɯɹǝqʎɔ "how many have negative" isn't enough, having one with -10 has greater meaning than 5 with -1 each.

Comment: @ShadowWizard That's what I meant; how many *posts* have negative votes. 5x -1 posts is likely to be more significant than 10x upvoted questions and 1x question at -10.